# Nginx - proxy request to URL specified in request Header

Tags: api, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, dynamic-routing

I have a strange requirement, My System is using NGNIX as a reverse proxy. where each request is redirected to URL specified in request header itself.

For e.g.
Request 1:

```
http://localhost/test 
---
X-ROUTE = "http://backend.com"
--- other headers
```

should be redirected to http://backend.com/test
Similarly

```
http://localhost/test
{
X-ROUTE = "http://demo.service.com"
}
```

should be redirected to http://demo.service.com/test

Since the upstream server cannot directly access these URL, we have to take this approach.

Each request recivied in NGINX reverse proxy should be parsed to get the url from the 'X-ROUTE' header value and then it should be routed in the same url we recieved in X-ROUTE